# How to obtain raphides from plants?

Tags: botany, microscopy

I recently found out that certain plants produce needle-shaped crystals called [raphides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raphide). I am a physicist and I have an experiment in mind that could use these needles, but I would need to extract them from the plant and keep them in a liquid solution somehow.

How can I do this? Is this possible/hard to do? Does anybody know how to do this or have any experience?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for raphide purification I came up with a paper where they isolate these crystals from kiwi fruit:

[Konno, K., Inoue, T. A., & Nakamura, M. (2014). Synergistic defensive function of raphides and protease through the needle effect. PloS one, 9(3).](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3951349/)

Does that help?

Note, however, that while according to this paper these large crystals can be kept in suspension that isn't the same as a solution ...